# Explicit computation of exterior power of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, exterior-algebra

I am following the excellent book by Ellinsgrud and Ottem, Introduction to Schemes.

When proving that the $n$-th exterior power of the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$, they simply say that:

$ \wedge^n \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n} = \wedge^n \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{n+1},$

and that the later is equals to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-n-1)$. Can someone provide a reference for this equality, or gave me some hint on how to do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Euler exact sequence
$$
0 \to \Omega \to \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus (n+1)} \to \mathcal{O} \to 0
$$
and multiplicativity of determinant with respect to exact sequences.

Comment: And how can one prove that these determinants coincides with $\mathcal{O}(-n-1)$?

Comment: @User43029 $\bigwedge^{n+1}(\mathcal O(-1)^{\oplus n+1})$ is a line bundle on projective space hence determined by its degree. This is the same as the degree of the underlying vector bundle, which is additive over direct sums, so $\deg \mathcal O(-1)^{\oplus n+1} = (n+1)\deg\mathcal O(-1) = (n+1)(-1) = -n-1$, so the determinant is $\mathcal O(-n-1)$.